# How to Override default update_count_callback for category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, callbacks

Is it possible to override default `update_count_callback` for category? The default function counts published posts while I want to count private posts. I do not want to register a new taxonomy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your update_count_callback function do a check for $post->post_status and don't increment your count if post_status is not private.

See this [excellent answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26433/251) on writing a custom update_count_callback callback function.

### Edit:

Misread the question. To override the existing default for the category taxonomy you can create a function that overrides the global $wp_taxonomies variable

```
function change_category_arg() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists('category') )
        return false;
            
    $new_arg = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback;
    $new_arg->update_count_callback = 'your_new_arg';
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_category_arg' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats for custom taxonomy. I want to override `category`s callback. I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @afnrf Category is a taxonomy. And you'll notice that he targets 'category' in his answer