# Change categories count to include media attachments

Tags: categories, taxonomy, attachments, media, count

I am creating a gallery that will automatically display new images from a chosen category and its subcategories. I have set up the categories so that they will apply to media using:
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );

Now I need to make it so that categories will count the related attachments not just posts.
I found this link [How to Override default update_count_callback for category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50932/how-to-override-default-update-count-callback-for-category) with this code:

```
function change_category_arg() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists('category') )
        return false;

    $new_arg = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback;
    $new_arg->update_count_callback = 'your_new_arg';

}
add_action( 'init', 'change_category_arg' );
```

But as of yet I have not figured it out (not sure if it doesn't work or if I'm just not understanding something, such as what would be 'your_new_arg').
I did find the update_count_callback function option when registering a new taxonomy but I don't want to make my own, I want to use it with the existing category taxonomy.

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this, but for anyone else that needs this:

`$wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback = '_update_generic_term_count';`

> This is significant in the case of attachments. Because an attachment
>   is a type of post, the default _update_post_term_count() will be used.
>   However, this may be undesirable, because this will only count
>   attachments that are actually attached to another post (like when you
>   insert an image into a post). This means that attachments that you
>   simply upload to WordPress using the Media Library, but do not
>   actually attach to another post will not be counted. If your intention
>   behind associating a taxonomy with attachments was to leverage the
>   Media Library as a sort of Document Management solution, you are
>   probably more interested in the counts of unattached Media items, than
>   in those attached to posts. In this case, you should force the use of
>   _update_generic_term_count() by setting '_update_generic_term_count' as the value for update_count_callback.

from [Wordpress Codex on register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)